# Add meta field just after post is published

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom field of event_month when a post is published or saved. I'm using the save_post action and getting the contents of a custom field containing the date and trying to store this in a separate custom field with just the month. This works perfectly when saving a post that has already been created. I've shown my code below.

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_event_date');

function update_event_date($post_id){

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
    $event_datee = get_post_meta($post_id, '_EventStartDate', true);

    if ($post_type == 'tribe_events'){

        $month = date("m",strtotime($event_datee));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'event_month', $month);

    }

}
```

The problem arises when creating a new post. I think this is because the action fires before the _EventStartDate meta has been created and therefore the month can't be taken from this.

The hook is firing correctly and as intended when saving/updating a post but doesn't correctly get the month from the meta when creating a new post.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could provide me with some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

To access post meta passed together with yours, you can do something like this:

```
$event_datee = get_post_meta($post_id, '_EventStartDate', true);
foreach($_POST['meta'] as $meta){
     if($meta['key'] == '_EventStartDate'){
           $event_datee = $meta['value'];
      }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. When going to add a new post I'm getting an error 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' and when I go to add a new event anyway, the $event_datee variable is empty..

Comment: Hmm, should work if you have any meta fields for the post. Try to `var_dump($_POST);` to see is there your meta?

Comment: Also try to change priority for your hook like `add_action('save_post', 'update_event_date', 99);`

Comment: Thank you! You give me the idea to go and find the solution.  For some reason in the var_dump it was showing the meta field as event_start_date, differently to how it was being shown in the database as _EventStartDate.  I assume this was something the plugin was doing, but I got the date I wanted from $_POST['event_start_date'] and was able to convert this to the month. So thanks for your help!